# How to create link in SharePoint custom text field?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created custom text field **MyItemURL**, I am trying to achieve thru coding if user click on **Click Me** the link should open, but in my coding entire url is appearing under **MyItemURL**. Just wanted to display **Click Me** link, how can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
string completeURL="MyItemComplete URL generated here";
listitem["MyItemURL"]="<a href=\"" + completeURL +  "\"> Click Me </a>";
listitem.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `listitem["MyItemURL"]="<a href=\"" + completeURL +  "\"> Click Me </a>` you are assigning the **value** of a *text* field, **not** an HTML fragment. If you want a URL field, then use [`SPFieldUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurl%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and not `SPFieldText`.